# How do I get dynamic checkboxe's value in express using body-parser?

Tags: arrays, express, object, checkbox, ejs

I'm still learning to code, I'm trying to make a to do list where you can add an element and delete it. I simply add the element to a db table and then delete that from that table. Actually I'm using express, body-parser and ejs and postgresql as db.
I have dyniamic checkboxes and I want to get the selected checkboxes but i have a doubt, because when I request the keys in my ejs (html) file, it returns me an array instead of an object as I've been told.
My code actually works, but I was wondering what would happen if I had not only checkboxes but other types of elements.

I do this when it comes to delete the checked elements.

```
app.post("/delete" , (req , res) => {
    const selectedItems = Object.keys(req.body);
    for (let i= 0; i<selectedItems.length; i++) {
        db.query("DELETE FROM list WHERE list_item = ($1)" , [selectedItems[i]]);
    }
    res.redirect("/");
    console.log(selectedItems);
    
});
```

`
I've been told that selectedItems should return an object with all the keys and their values (checkboxes, radios etc.) but it actually returns an array with the key names.
Let's say list has the elements A, B and C, and I select only A and B it would return ["A", "B"].
This is my ejs code:

```
<form action="/delete" method="post">
    <button><span class="material-symbols-outlined">
        close
        </span></button>

<ul>
    <input type="radio" name="radio">
    <% for (let list_item of item) {%>
           <li> <input type="checkbox" name="<%= list_item %>"> <%= list_item%></li> 
           <% } %>
    </ul>
</form>
```

As you can see, i put list_item as name of every checkbox so it is the same as the element of the list.
I also added a random radio to see what it does, and it actually just gives me the radio name in the same array. Now, how would I know which one is the radio and which one is the checkbox? I'm I doing something wrong?
Thanks for helping!